# Is it still safe to use ImageX for capturing and applying Windows 7 images, even if it's deprecated, and how is it compatible with DISM?

Tags: windows-7, dism, imagex, waik, adk

ImageX has been flagged by Microsoft as a deprecated tool. Is it still safe to use it for capturing and applying Windows 7 images? There are some tutorials about using DISM instead of ImageX with Windows 7 images, but DISM included in Windows AIK doesn't have options /Apply-Image and /Capture-Image. Microsoft's article [Installing the Windows ADK](https://technet.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/hh825494.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) says that ADK also applies to Windows 7, but it links to download page, which says it's for Windows 8.1.
If it's possible - is it better to use Windows ADK's DISM for capturing and applying Windows 7 images or it's risky or it doesn't matter at all? If it's better - is it safe to apply images with ADK's DISM which was previously captured with ImageX?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**ImageX** is no longer supported by **Microsoft**, instead **DISM** is being used to capture and deploy images. But for me if you only use Windows 7 for imaging and you do not have any plans to move to Windows 8, then you may continue with ImageX. But if you want to move to Windows 8 in the near future then you should use DISM.

The advantage with DISM is that it supports both Windows 7 and Windows 8. So the mixed environment does not matter for DISM unlike ImageX. Also the process of using DISM is quite similar to ImageX.

So in conclusion, you should continue with ImageX if you plans to stick to Windows 7, you should not change something that works well for you. But if you want to move to Windows 8, them it's better to start using DISM.

Thank you.

Comment: If DISM works with Windows 7, maybe it would be good to start using this to learn something new. And also I could use only one tool instead of using ImageX for applying and capturing and AIK's DISM for mounting images. Thanks for answer.

Comment: I asked this question, because sometimes there was a problem when installing drivers, because it kept freezing near 60% and didn't end even after very long time. I thought there was something wrong with ImageX, but now I discovered that I have to use `/forceunsigned` attribute when adding drivers to mounted image and then it works perfects, installation of all drivers takes about 2-3 minutes. I hope this information will be useful for someone else.

Comment: It helped with one PC, but the other model had the same problem, it stucked at 55% and `/forceunsigned` attribute didn't help. Solution was disconnecting USB mouse before restarting PC after applying image. I spent so much time with this, trying so many things, it freaks me out...